# After fixing error "Root element paints background" why image is repeated in other view?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-styles, appcompatactivity

After fixing "Possible overdraw: Root element paints background" error new issue is arise in my splash activity; the image set in background is repeated in progressbar background

here is my **manifiest.xml** code

```
<activity
            android:name="com.dictionary.SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

**splash.xml code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:theme="@style/BrownColor" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**and java code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.three_splash);}
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
 </style>

 <style name="BrownColor" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">#8e2308</item>
 </style>
```

**and screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, you are setting background in your activity style, this means you are setting that background for all view within it. Just remove that line

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
```

If you are creating splash screen - use windowBackground instead

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve